# Adding elements of 2 linked list in reverse order

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I solved a problem with JavaScript which has the following requirements:

1. Two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers.
2. Digits stored in reverse order
3. Each node contains a single digit
4. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list

Sample I/O:

```
Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807
```

My code:

```
 /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.next = null;
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
  let l1Str = "";
  let l2Str = "";
  while (l1 !== null) {
    l1Str += l1.val.toString();
    l1 = l1.next;
  }

  while (l2 !== null) {
    l2Str += l2.val.toString();
    l2 = l2.next;
  }

  let sum = (BigInt(l1Str.split("").reverse().join("")) + BigInt(l2Str.split("").reverse().join(""))).toString();

  let resultNodeList = new ListNode(sum[sum.length - 1]);
  let resultHead = resultNodeList;
  for (let i = sum.length - 2;i >= 0;i--) {
    resultNodeList.next = new ListNode(sum[i]);
    resultNodeList = resultNodeList.next;
  }

  return resultHead;

};
```

Note: I had to use `BigInt` cause `parseInt` won't work on big integers as expected.

Although it passed all test cases, what are some ways to improve this code in terms of both time and space complexity?

Comment: In my opinion, using `BigInt` to perform the addition is considered cheating.

Answer (score 2):

### Here are a list of improvements:

1. Use ECMAScript features and syntax
2. Create own implementation of BigInt
3. Don't use strings !
4. Create functions to regroup similar code and reduce code duplication

### Detailed Explanation:

Generates a ListNode from a given array (array should already be reversed).

```
generateListNode = (list) => {
 const [ele] = list;
 //create the sentinel (starting point of the node list)
 const sentinel = new ListNode(ele);
 let current = sentinel;
 for(let i = 1; i < list.length; i++){
   //update the next with the new list node
   //set the current to the new next
   current = current.next = new ListNode(list[i]);
 }
 return sentinel;
}
```

---

Convert a ListNode to an Array

```
const convertToValueList = (list) => {
  const res = [];
  //as long as the value "list" is not null it'll continue the loop
  //push the list.val to the result array
  do { res.push(list.val); } while(list = list.next);
  return res;
}
```

---

addTwoNumbers has it's own implementation of BigInt

```
const addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {

  //Convert the ListNode to arrays
  const l1Values = convertToValueList(l1);
  const l2Values = convertToValueList(l2);

  //find the longest of either list
  const len = Math.max(l1Values.length, l2Values.length);

  //when adding a column, value should not exceed 9, otherwise it'll be set to the remainder
  //i.e.: 10 -> 1, 23 -> 2, 30 -> 3
  let remainder = 0;
  //final result in reverse
  const sum = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    //add the sum of each value of the list at the "i" position
    //if the value does not exist (i.e.: undefined) use default 0
    //add the remainder if it exists
    const tempSum = (l1Values[i] || 0) + (l2Values[i] || 0) + remainder;
    //update the remainder (any value under 10 is set to 0 because of Math.floor)
    remainder = Math.max(Math.floor(tempSum/10), 0);
    //add the value (modulo 10 so only numbers 0 - 9 are added)
    sum.push(tempSum % 10);
  }

  console.log(sum);
  //generate the list node and return final result
  return generateListNode(sum);
};
```

### Working Example:

```js
class ListNode {
  constructor(val){
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
  }  
}

generateListNode = (list) => {
  const [ele] = list;
  const sentinel = new ListNode(ele);
  let current = sentinel;
  for(let i = 1; i < list.length; i++){
    current = current.next = new ListNode(list[i]);
  }
  return sentinel;
}

const list1 = generateListNode([2, 4, 3]);
const list2 = generateListNode([5, 6, 4]);

const convertToValueList = (list) => {
  const res = [];
  do { res.push(list.val); } while(list = list.next);
  return res;
}

const addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {

  const l1Values = convertToValueList(l1);
  const l2Values = convertToValueList(l2);
  
  const len = Math.max(l1Values.length, l2Values.length);
  
  let remainder = 0;
  const sum = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
     const tempSum = (l1Values[i] || 0) + (l2Values[i] || 0) + remainder;
remainder = Math.floor(tempSum/10);
     sum.push(tempSum % 10);
  }

  console.log(sum);
  return generateListNode(sum);
};

const res = addTwoNumbers(list1, list2);
console.log(res);
```

### Additional:

The best case scenario is if you have the option to add methods to `ListNode`.

```js
class BodyNode {
  constructor(val){
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class ListNode extends BodyNode {
  
  static FromArray(list){
     if(list.length === 0) throw new Error("Array cannot be of length 0");
     const clone = list.slice();
     const instance = new ListNode(clone.shift());
     while(clone.length > 0){
       instance.add(clone.shift());
     }
     return instance;
  }

  constructor(val){
    super(val);
    this.last = this;
  }
  
  add(val){
    this.last = this.last.next = new BodyNode(val);
  }
  
  toArray(){
    const res = [];
    let current = this;
    do { res.push(current.val); } while(current = current.next);
    return res;
  }
  
}

const list1 = ListNode.FromArray([2, 4, 3]);
const list2 = ListNode.FromArray([5, 6, 4]);

const addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {

  const l1Arr = l1.toArray();
  const l2Arr = l2.toArray();
  
  const len = Math.max(l1Arr.length, l2Arr.length);
  
  let remainder = 0;
  const sum = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
     const tempSum = (l1Arr[i] || 0) + (l2Arr[i] || 0) + remainder;
     remainder = Math.floor(tempSum/10);
     sum.push(tempSum % 10);
  }

  console.log(sum);
  return ListNode.FromArray(sum);
};

const res = addTwoNumbers(list1, list2);
console.log(res);
```